# WHERE clause not evaluated remotely when querying Azure SQL external table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm pulling bits of data from one Azure SQL database to another, using the [external tables](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/) feature.

As described under "performance improvements", it's important to ensure WHERE clauses are evaluated on the remote server. This ensures only the required rows are returned, as opposed to returning the whole remote table and filtering it on the local server.

This works fine for a query like:
`SELECT column_list FROM remote_table WHERE some_clause`

However, if I combine it with a local insert:
`INSERT INTO local_table (column_list) SELECT column_list FROM remote_table WHERE some_clause`

.. suddenly the whole table is returned, and some_clause is evaluated locally instead, imposing a huge performance hit.
I'm unable to reproduce the issue between two local SQL instances (admittedly using linked servers instead of external tables). WHERE is always evaluated remotely as expected.

Why the discrepancy?
Is there a way to nudge the query optimizer in the right direction?

(SELECT INTO actually works as expected on Azure, so the practical workaround seems to be a temp table.)

**Update:**
The problem is only reproducible with IDENTITY_INSERT = ON for the local table, and when the local ID is being inserted from the remote table.

Assuming [Id] is a local identity column, this triggers the issue:
`SET IDENTITY_INSERT local_table ON;`
`INSERT INTO local_table (Id) SELECT Id FROM remote_table WHERE Id = 1;`

However, specifying the Id instead of pulling it works fine:
`INSERT INTO local_table (Id) SELECT 1 FROM remote_table WHERE Id = 1;`

Comment: Creating a temp table seems like a good workaround.

Comment: It works, @AlbertoMorillo - but comes with some overhead. Would be nice to figure out the root cause.

Comment: Let me share your question with more people and if I got a better workaround/solution for you. Please describe a little bit more about the overhead. How many records returned to the temp table.

Comment: The overhead associated with temp table materializing and tracking is absolutely negligible in my use case (hundreds of rows / tens of tables), so I already implemented this solution. The question is mostly academic, but I'd like to find out if the execution discrepancy stems from a query optimizer bug, or some other interesting reason.